# AngularJS: How does controller know it should use a mocked dependency in place of original one?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine

The dependency injection in tests is confusing to me.
Specifically in [chapter 5](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#test) of the official tutorial, I can see that $httpBackend is configured to provide a fake response:

```
$httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
$httpBackend.expectGET('phones/phones.json').
    respond([{name: 'Nexus S'}, {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);
```

But what I can't see is that why the controller wants to use this newly defined dependency instead of the original `$http` introduced in `PhoneListCtrl` definition.

In the same code snippet, if the controller was initialized with something like this:

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {
                                     $scope: scope,
                                     $http: $httpBackend});
```

I could understand that we are overriding the dependency so when the controller wants to access `$http`, it will use our mocked one.

But given that't not the case in the mentioned tutorial:

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope: scope});
```

and only the scope is passed to `$controller`, I can't see anything that would link the `$httpBackend` to the controller.

I am just confused how the controller knows about the new mocked service/dependency.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$http` isn't being replaced with `$httpBackend`. `$http` uses `$httpBackend` internally. Without the `ngMock` module it's using the [service documented here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpBackend). Then, when including the `ngMock` module, it uses the [service documented here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend). So with the `ngMock` module, it is just giving a different definition for what the `$httpBackend` service is.